# How to customize returnurl when it redirect to Login page after unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

```cs
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddToCart(int itemNumber)
{
    // do somthing here...
    return RedirectToAction("CartList");
}
```

When I submit the form to above action from `/Shop/ProductDetail?id=42` page without login, It will automatic redirect the page to

- /Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=`%2FCart%2FAddToCart`

How can I customize this default `returnurl` value to something else. like

- /Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=`<my custom return url>`

I try to add returnurl in form tag

```html
<form method="post" asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path@Context.Request.QueryString">
```

But it returns url like bellow

- /Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=`%2FCart%2FAddToCart%3FreturnUrl%252FShop%252FProductDetail%253Fid%253D42`

What I want is

- /Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=`/Shop/ProductDetail?id=42`

**Solution**
When I submit the form from `ProductDetail` view to `AddToCart` action, It will auto redirect the page to `Login` view. But the returnUrl is `/AddToCart` instead of `ProductDetail?itemNumber=10`.
So what I did:

1. passing the returnUrl from `ProductDetial` view form tag.

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path@Context.Request.QueryString">
```

2. This will redirect to `Login` view with the returnUrl contains bellow.

```
/Cart/AddToCart?returnUrl=%2FShop%2FProductDetail%3FitemNumber%3D10
```

3. So in `Login view` I extract the latest returnUrl

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginVM model, string returnUrl = null)
{
  returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
  var index = returnUrl.LastIndexOf(nameof(returnUrl));
  if (index != -1)
  {
    returnUrl = returnUrl.Substring(index + nameof(returnUrl).Length + 1);
    returnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(returnUrl);
    //returnUrl : /Shop/ProductDetail?id=42
  }
}
```

I'm not sure this is right approach?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-5.0#using-a-named-route) suggest you use `ViewData` to store the return url, so when getting `ProductDetail` try to set `ViewData["ReturnUrl"]` to `"/Shop/ProductDetail?id={replace_by_item_id}` and then follow the example:

```
asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]"
```

Comment: What about if you r not using Razor pages but instead a external spa like, for example, React? Noticed similar behaviors that it re-directs me to `/Identity/Account/Login`

Comment: If you want to handle authorization client side you use an interceptor and redirect from there to wherever you want on unauthorized requests. Which is not the case in OP question.