# http 405 after use [Authorize] and login

Tags: c#, .net, authorize

I am writing a simple pet online shop website and I was trying to check user login status if they press the add to cart button, and if they logged in they are able to add the product to cart, if they not log in, they will redirect log in page and login first then do all the function, I am using `.NET Core` found there is  `[Authorize]` function, so I just put this front of my AddToCart method, however I found a issue is if user not login, press button will lead the login page, and once logged in, the URL will go to `https://localhost:7281/Carts/AddtoCart?productId=4` (because I press the product that id =4) and shows http405, but if i manually go back to home page, because is already logged in, i press the button again, is working fine and go to the carts index page, so the question is how could page can go carts index page at the first time? it seems like even I logged in the computer still can't detect I logged in, I need to manually go back the page and do it again, every one had same issue before? here is my `AddToCart` code

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(int productId)
        {
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            var cart = await _context.Carts
                .Include(c => c.CartItems)
                .ThenInclude(ci => ci.Products)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.UserId == userId);

            var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(productId);

            if (cart == null)
            {
                cart = new Cart { UserId = userId };
                cart.CartItems = new List<CartItem> { new CartItem { Products = product, Quantity = 1 } };
                _context.Carts.Add(cart);
            }
            else
            {
                var cartItem = cart.CartItems.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.Products.Id == productId);
                if (cartItem == null)
                {
                    cart.CartItems.Add(new CartItem { Products = product, Quantity = 1 });
                }
                else
                {
                    cartItem.Quantity += 1;
                }
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Carts", new { area = "", page = "index" });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can check for the `ReturnUrl` that is generated when the user is not logged in and is redirected to login page:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddToCart(int productId)
{
    string returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Carts", new { area = "", page = "index" });
    }
       
    var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

    var cart = await _context.Carts
        .Include(c => c.CartItems)
        .ThenInclude(ci => ci.Products)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.UserId == userId);

    var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(productId);

    if (cart == null)
    {
        cart = new Cart { UserId = userId };
        cart.CartItems = new List<CartItem> { new CartItem { Products = product, Quantity = 1 } };
        _context.Carts.Add(cart);
    }
    else
    {
        var cartItem = cart.CartItems.FirstOrDefault(ci => ci.Products.Id == productId);
        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            cart.CartItems.Add(new CartItem { Products = product, Quantity = 1 });
        }
        else
        {
            cartItem.Quantity += 1;
        }
    }

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Carts", new { area = "", page = "index" });
```

Comment: tried, same result... if not login, when i click add to cart button will always go to login page,but since login will immidiately go to https://localhost:7281/Carts/AddtoCart?productId=4 url, seems this action will ignore my RedirectToAction code as no matter what i put will always stop Carts/AddtoCart?productId=4 ....

Comment: @user3528204 What url is genrated when you go to login page and the user is not authenticated? My point is that when the user is not authenticated, they are redirected to the login page. What is the url generated at that time?

Comment: https://localhost:7281/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FCarts%2FAddtoCart%3FproductId%3D4  this is the url generrate after i press the button

Comment: @user3528204 Check updated answer that checks for the `ReturnUrl` param in query string and if it finds it, then it redirects as required

Comment: i copy paste string returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Carts", new { area = "", page = "index" });
    } but still lead to the same url....any suggestion?

Comment: @user3528204 When you place a break point, what values do you get in your `returnUrl` variable?

Comment: I have never use break point before.. where should i set the break point? i tried set at return RedirectToAction("Index", "Carts", new { area = "", page = "index" }); but no any result came out. i am assuming the login function will automically back to the action itself url after logged in, so for explample if the button I hit is proforme AddToCart Action which the url will be Post:Carts/AddToCart/ProductId , because i used  [Authorize], so after logged in the return url will return the same url which is Carts/AddToCart/ProductId, so is anyway can forcce change login function to redirect?

Comment: @user3528204 Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65751537/how-to-customize-returnurl-when-it-redirect-to-login-page-after-unauthorized . I think you should extract out the returnUrl in your `Login` method and then perform the action on it as required. Since you have not posted your `Login` method, you can follow the step that I did for `returnUrl` logic.

Comment: i didnt create login method, i just tick individual account user when i build this project, and i can't found the function can change the accoutant function, all i can find is only view, but no controller related accoutant..

Comment: @rahhul sharma found a solution which is not actully solve this question but atlest a way can run. instead of redirect the carts page after doing the function, i change to if didnt found the user id ,just go back to the main login page, as i found in the main login page the return url is home page, so at least wont cause any error ,and after logged in, user are able to add to cart with no problem!